# Как выбрать из таблицы минимальные значения, упорядоченные по другому столбцу?

Tags: sql, mysqli

Есть таблица

[image: Таблица MySQL]

Подскажите, как выбрать все уникальные name, упорядоченные по id с минимальным price?

Делаю `SELECT * FROM`data`GROUP BY name ORDER BY id`, получаю все, что хотел, но значения price не минимальные

[image: Таблица с выборкой]

Comment: SELECT min(id) as id, name, min(price) as min_price  FROM data GROUP BY name ORDER BY id

Comment: *значения price не минимальные* Да и `id` минимальные, на самом деле, чисто случайно.

Comment: @Konst Неполный `GROUP BY` же ж... есть ненулевой шанс, что `id` в сортировке окажется не тот, что в агрегате. Надо `ORDER BY 1` - он гарантирует порядок. Или `ORDER BY MIN(id)`

Comment: order by копипас, он и не нужен

Comment: Большое спасибо, разобрался с min()

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно и выбирать минимальную цену, в противном случае значение будет взято из одной из строк.

```
select min(id) id, name, min(price) price from a group by name order by id
```

Comment: Благодарю, разобрался!

Comment: Данный запрос будет корректен, только если каждому дубликату name соответствует один и тот же id (возможно это так и есть, не вижу картинок)

Comment: @ГерманБорисов почему же? выбирается же минимальный `id` и заносится под alias с тем же именем

Comment: если есть две записи с одинаковым name, но у той, у которой меньше id больше price, то будет выведен id от одной записи, а price - от другой

Comment: Если нужно ещё и соответствие id-шек, то тогда так:

`select a.id, a.name, b.price
from a
inner join (
    select name, min(price) price
    from a group by name
) b on a.name = b.name and a.price = b.price
order by a.id`